# The best way to divide card-deck into rows in django template

Tags: django

[What I have(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfkmh.jpg)
So i need to divide these cards into 4-5 cards per row.
My solution is simple

```
<div class="card-deck">
    {% for book in books %}
        {% include 'books/book_element.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And I have tried for a while and was doing some brainstorm

```
    {% for book in books %}
        {% if  forloop.counter|divisibleby:"5" or forloop.counter == 1 %}
            <div class="card-deck">
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

How can I include a template into a div.card-deck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the previous row and open a new one in your loop. Something like this:

```
<div class="card-deck">
    {% for book in books %}
        {% include 'books/book_element.html' %}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"5"  %}
            {# Close the current deck and start a new one %}
            </div><div class="card-deck">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div><!-- The final deck is closed here, outside the loop -->
```